# Can I fit a view to (0.0, 0.0) with navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, view, navigationcontroller

I have a viewController pushed in navigationController.

When this viewController pushed, the navigation bar was attached on top(0.0, 0.0), and

the viewController's view was attached just under that. (maybe.. 0.0, 44.0)

But, I want this view to locate to (0.0, 0.0) with navigation bar.

Namely, the top side of the view have to be covered beneath the navigation bar.

Thank you for your reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this apple has provided `barStyle` and `translucent` properties for `navigationBar`. It will reduce navigation bar's *opacity* and will start your viewcontroller from `statusBar`. It will look like what we see in **Photo** app.

In this case your view controller will be partially visible (as alpha for navigation bar will become < 1). I don't know whether this solves your purpose or not.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html

Thanks,

Comment: Oh, this is the best answer to me. The problem have been solved well. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you show your view controller, do this on the navigation controller.

```
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

It will hide the navigation bar and the view controller will be all the way to the top.

Comment: My problem is not this. But, Thank you for your care.